# Excel if(match()) function across multiple sheets is returning #N/A

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, match

```
=IF(MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)>=1,"",Sheet1!A1)
```

The logic seems to be working as matches return "" but unique values return #N/A.

Is this a problem from referencing values from across multiple sheets?

Thanks.

**Update:**

Reading more about Match() and saw that it returns #N/A not 0 if no match is found, so I tried:

```
=IF(MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)="#N/A",Sheet1!A1,"")
```

and that also returns #N/A

Comment: It does not matter if it is across sheets or within a single sheet.  If `MATCH()` fails, you get an error.

Comment: Can I use this error to my advantage to place the value of the looked up item Sheet1A1?

Comment: Use `IFERROR()` to detect the failed match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it as,

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Sheet1!A2, Sheet2!A:A, 0)), "",Sheet1!A2)
```

Logic: If there is a match, return a zero-length string. If there is no match, return the original lookup value.